# vis timeline - items.add breaks loop when called from async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise, timeline

I am adding multiple items to a vis timeline:
The first adding is called inside a callback and works fine.
The second time I am adding data which comes from an async ajax request and returns a promise.
 `getRocketChat().then(print);`
The problem is now, that the loop is only executed once when I do the item adding. When I uncomment the item adding it works fine.
I also tried around with `timeline.redraw()`, `items.update()` etc, but with no success. I absolutely have no idea why this does not work.

```
function print(channelAndMessages) {

    for (let i = 0; i < channelAndMessages.length; i++) {
        console.log(channelAndMessages[i]);

        for (let j = 0; j < channelAndMessages[i].messages.length; j++) {
            console.log("ChannelName " + getChannelName(channelAndMessages[i].messages[j].rid));

            let singleMsg = channelAndMessages[i].messages[j];

            items.add({
                id: "Chat" + singleMsg.id,
                group: 'einsatzltr',
                content: singleMsg.msg,
                start: moment(singleMsg.ts)

            });
            console.log(singleMsg.msg); //excecuted only once
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It has nothing to do with the loop, but just with the id.
I changed the item id to another function and now it works:

```
 id: "Chat" + i +" " + j,
```